# Bootstrap col without size or weight

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get bootstrap grid working.
From the bootstrap website :
[bootstrap documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)
 it makes it seem like you can just put col and it'll have a default value of all sizes and divide the weight of 12 by the number of cols in the row

They have an example of this on the site

```
<div class="container">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However when I put it on my page or other bootstrap testing websites, that code makes the 3 cols stacked on top of each other like

```
1 of 3
1 of 3
1 of 3
```

How do I achieve something like the bootstrap website?

Comment: Can you include the `<link>` tag, in the example above, that you're using to reference bootstrap in your page?

Comment: Ok I added the link

Comment: I meant: Add to your example the actual HTML `<link>` tag referencing the bootstrap.css file you're using. ;)

Comment: I am running bootstrap 3 with bootstrap-loader and webpack.

I think that might be the problem. The tutorial seems to be written for bootstrap 4 as I loaded the cdn version of bootstrap 4 and it works.

Comment: That's why I asked for the link tag. ;) Glad you got it working!